# linear Combination And The Zero Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the notion that every linear combination with zero is linear dependent because every scalar that is not zero can be attach to it.
So that mean that every space with the zero vector must be linear dependent and that mean that the basis must not include the zero vector?

Comment: Everything you write is correct except for the phrase "every *space* with the zero vector..."  A set of vectors that could form a basis is hardly a *space.*

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think the OP was asking:

"I came across a result that any subset of a vector space containing the zero vector is linearly dependent. So does this mean that a basis must not include the zero vector?"

The answer is yes...since one of the properties of a basis is that it is a set of linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the zero vector causing linear dependence. For every vector space, the vectors in it it are a linearly dependent set since by definition they include all (finite) linear combinations. For example, if $a\in V$ then $\alpha.a \in V$ (where $\alpha$ is an element of the underlying field) and therefore $V$ is linearly dependent.

Alternatively, consider that a basis is a linearly independent set of vectors that spans $V$, so once you add any other vector to it (i.e. some or all of the rest of $V$) you have a linearly dependent set.

You are correct that the zero vector cannot be in any linearly indepedent set, so specifically it can't be in a basis.